Make checkout field required if shipping class is applicable
With WooCommerce, I would like to make checkout field billing_company required if a certain shipping class is applicable for the order.
I found similar code snippets, but they are all looking at the shipping method, not the class. I tried both options for $shipping_classes in the next code snippet, but it's not working.
Any thoughts?
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_company_checkout_field_required');

function make_company_checkout_field_required($fields) {
    $shipping_class ='heavy-shipping-class'; // Set the desired shipping class.
    global $woocommerce;
    //$shipping_classes = WC()->session->get( 'product_shipping_class' );
    $shipping_classes = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_shipping_class' ) );
    $chosen_shipping_class = $shipping_classes[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping_class == $shipping_class) {
       $fields['billing']['billing_company'][ 'required' ] = true;
    }
    return $fields;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_company_checkout_field_required');

function make_company_checkout_field_required($fields) {
    // Define the shipping class slug you want to check for
    $shipping_class_slug = 'heavy-shipping-class'; // Adjust this to your desired shipping class slug
    $make_company_required = false;

    // Loop through all the items in the cart to check their shipping class
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // Get the product's shipping class ID
        $product_shipping_class_id = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
        
        // Get the shipping class object by ID
        $shipping_class = get_term($product_shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class');
        
        // Check if the product's shipping class matches the target class
        if ($shipping_class && $shipping_class->slug === $shipping_class_slug) {
            $make_company_required = true;
            break; // No need to continue looping once we find a matching class
        }
    }

    // If a product with the specified shipping class is found, make the company field required
    if ($make_company_required) {
        $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = true;
    }

    return $fields;
}



Try to use this code for it.

Please explain how this code addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers - Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

If you can read then check- every line have comment to explain. Thanks!

@Sjors If you have a new question, then post a new question. Questions on StackOverflow should focus on one problem at the time

As pointed out already, this answer has a high chance of being generated with GPT, unsure if you will get any decent response.

I can understand @DarkBee, But I have 7+ years of experience in WordPress to develop custom things. I will improve next time my answer format with explanation.
